# How to style md-select icon?

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I use `angular-material` and specifically its `<md-select/>` component.
I would like to style it's icon:
[image]

We used to override its css using the class `.md-select-icon` but it seems to have been the wrong approach and recently the classes have been changed to reflect they are for "private" use (`.md-select-icon` renamed to `._md-select-icon`)

Question is - How can I do a custom override of the `.md-select` icon, the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.md-select-value .md-select-icon {
    background: #fff url("image/common/selector/normal.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for font based solution, use following CSS.

```css
.md-select-value .md-select-icon:after {
    font-family: Material Icons;
    font-size: 24px;
    content: 'keyboard_arrow_down';
    display: inline;
    top: 5px;
    transform: scale(1);
    font-feature-settings: 'liga'; /* Support for IE. From material-icons.css. */
}
```